# CodeSign error: No code signing identities found

Tags: ios-simulator, appcode

I want to run the simulator in AppCode. I get the error above because I haven't registered with apple yet, but I cannot figure out how to run the simulator. 
[This link](http://blog.jetbrains.com/objc/2013/06/run-configurations-vs-schemes/) claims shows how to create a run configuration, but makes no mention of specifying a simulator or a real device. How is this done?

Answer (score 0):

The answer is, from the **Run** menu, select **Run...** not **Edit Configurations...**
Then you can select which simulator you want to run. It will then compile and run.